# How would you move particular datas to front of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

There are like these datas

```js
const persons = [
  {
    label: "jhon",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    label: "Mary",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    label: "Michelle",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    label: "David",
    value: 4
  },
  {
    label: "Kerry",
    value: 5
  },
  {
    label: "Tom",
    value: 6
  }
];
```

```js
const testPassedPersons = [3, 5, 6];
```

### What do I want to do?

I need to move these persons who includes testPassedPersons number to head of array.
So now Michelle / Kerry / Tom should move, value in order from smallest to largest [3,5,6]

▼ What I need to get

```js
const SortedPersons = [
  {
    label: "Michelle",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    label: "Kerry",
    value: 5
  },
  {
    label: "Tom",
    value: 6
  }
  {
    label: "jhon",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    label: "Mary",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    label: "David",
    value: 4
  },
];
```

### What I've tried so far

actually I have a solution, but I would like to know alternative better way (specially shorter or faster)

▼ This is my way

```js
const sortedPersons = [
  ...persons.filter((person) => testPassedPersons.includes(person.value)),
  ...persons.filter((person) => !testPassedPersons.includes(person.value))
];
```

▼ codesandbox url.
https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-david-1giqnk?file=/src/index.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+sort+using+another+array may help.

Comment: do you want the order of passed as well? or simply move this persons to top remaining their actual order?

Comment: btw your implemetation will give `Mary,Michelle,Kerry,Tom` for `[3, 5, 6, 2]` instead `Michelle,Kerry,Tom,Mary`  is that desired

Comment: @kazon what result do you need if [3,5,6,2]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got:

```
let sortedPersons = new Set();
testPassedPersons.forEach((passedPerson) => {
  persons.forEach((person) => {
    if (passedPerson === person.value) {
      sortedPersons.add(person);
    }
  });
});

persons.forEach((person) => sortedPersons.add(person));
sortedPersons = [...sortedPersons];

console.log(sortedPersons);
```

As code shows, I am creating a set because set will hold only unique values. We add the persons with the values in testPassedPersons, then add the rest of the persons. Since set holds unique items, the duplication won't occur.Then, at the end, we just turn that set into an array.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a [custom sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description) function.
`indexOf` returns `-1` if element is not found in the array.
So if `aIndex` is not -1 and `bIndex` is -1 it means both not found. therefore keep original order of a and b.
If `aIndex` is -1 only we return 1 means a should come after b.
If `bIndex` is -1 only we return -1 means a should come before b (b after a). So basically what is not found in `testPassedPersons` comes after.
Finally `indexA - indexB` will decide which comes first based on the sign.

```js
const persons = [  {    label: "jhon",    value: 1  },  {    label: "Mary",    value: 2  },  {    label: "Michelle",    value: 3  },  {    label: "David",    value: 4  },  {    label: "Kerry",    value: 5  },  {    label: "Tom",    value: 6  }];

const testPassedPersons = [3, 5, 6];

const res = [...persons].sort((a,b) => {
  const indexA = testPassedPersons.indexOf(a.value)
  const indexB = testPassedPersons.indexOf(b.value)
  if (indexA === -1 && indexB === -1) return 0;
  if (indexA === -1) return 1
  if (indexB === -1) return -1
  return indexA - indexB
  //or ternary operator
  //return (indexA === -1 && indexB === -1) ? 0 : (indexA === -1) ? 1 : (indexB === -1) ? -1 : indexA - indexB

})

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

the implementation with 2 filters will give `Mary,Michelle,Kerry,Tom` for `[3, 5, 6, 2]` instead `Michelle,Kerry,Tom,Mary`. If that is the desired result you can achieve it in 1 loop instead of 2 filters(2 loops) using `reduce`. Also converting the passed person array to a set can help achieve O(1) lookup

```js
const persons = [  {    label: "jhon",    value: 1  },  {    label: "Mary",    value: 2  },  {    label: "Michelle",    value: 3  },  {    label: "David",    value: 4  },  {    label: "Kerry",    value: 5  },  {    label: "Tom",    value: 6  }];

const testPassedPersons = [3, 5, 6, 2];
const testPassedPersonsSet = new Set(testPassedPersons)

const {passed,notPassed} = persons.reduce((acc,{label,value}) => {
  acc[testPassedPersonsSet.has(value) ? 'passed' : 'notPassed'].push({label,value})
  return acc
},{passed:[],notPassed:[]})

console.log([...passed,...notPassed])
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build an object with the wanted order and sort by `value` or move the items to bottom.

This approach allows to move any unknown item/`value` either to top (value smaller than zero), bottom (a large value, like `Number.MAX_VALUE`) or just inbetween the given order.

```js
const
    persons = [{ label: "jhon", value: 1 }, { label: "Mary", value: 2 }, { label: "Michelle", value: 3 }, { label: "David", value: 4 }, { label: "Kerry", value: 5 }, { label: "Tom", value: 6 }],
    testPassedPersons = [3, 5, 6],
    order = Object.fromEntries(testPassedPersons.map((v, i) => [v, i + 1]));

persons.sort((a, b) => (order[a.value] || Number.MAX_VALUE) - (order[b.value] || Number.MAX_VALUE));

console.log(persons);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything really wrong with your current approach. You could save yourself a loop over the array with a partition function rather than a filter function.

The idea with the partition function is to push the matching results into the first array (equivalent to the filter results) and then push all the others into a second array, so you have two arrays, one of matching and one of not matching results.

A number of JS libraries have partition functions e.g. [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#partition) and [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#partition).

```js
const persons = [{ label: "jhon", value: 1 }, { label: "Mary", value: 2 }, { label: "Michelle", value: 3 }, { label: "David", value: 4 }, { label: "Kerry", value: 5 }, { label: "Tom", value: 6 }];

const testPassedPersons = [3, 5, 6];

const partition = (data, partition_function) =>
  data.reduce(
    (acc, val) => (acc[+!partition_function(val)].push(val), acc),
    [[], []]
  );

const get_sorted_persons = persons =>
  partition(persons, (person) => testPassedPersons.includes(person.value)).flat();

console.log(get_sorted_persons(persons));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this with the help of [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method along with [`Array.unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const persons = [
  {
    label: "jhon",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    label: "Mary",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    label: "Michelle",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    label: "David",
    value: 4
  },
  {
    label: "Kerry",
    value: 5
  },
  {
    label: "Tom",
    value: 6
  }
];

const testPassedPersons = [3, 5, 6];

persons.forEach((obj, index) => {
    if (testPassedPersons.includes(obj.value)) {
    persons.splice(index, 1);
    persons.unshift(obj);
  }
});

console.log(persons)
```

Comment: order has to change? yours start with 6,5,3

Comment: @cmgchess Looks like he wants to move the matched objects at the start of the array. He did not mentioned anywhere about the order. So not sure if OP wants the result in some specific order or not.